# Files and folders lock

Tags: release-juno

I recently installed eos juno dual boot with windows 10. Initially i wasn't getting any kind of problems but from past few days sometimes files and folders get locked themselves automatically. I tried "chown" and "chmod" but nothing happened. After few days it unlocks all files and folders automatically but next day it gets locked again. Please help. I want to work on eos as my primary os for daily basis.

Comment: What do you mean by "get locked". Has it changed ownership somehow? Is it happening for files in user directory or a system managed directory?

Comment: @Sterex it is happening in the "user directory" as well as in "system directory". I don't know if it is changing ownership as "sudo chmod -R -v 777" and "sudo chown -R -v your_username:your_username" commands isn't working.

Comment: That is really odd. I'm sorry, I cannot be of much help until we know what is causing the issue.

Comment: Can you try these methods to find out what's happening with the files? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-program-or-script-created-a-given-file

Comment: @Sterex the lock files and folders have not been showing since yesterday. It unlocked automatically. I don't know when it will get locked again.